# Angulartics2: startTracking() does not exist on type 'Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics'

Tags: angular, google-analytics, angulartics2

I've followed the instructions on the [readme](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2/tree/next#installation) of [Angulartics2](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2) for Google Analytics:

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { Angulartics2Module } from 'angulartics2';
import { Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics } from 'angulartics2/ga';
...
imports: [Angulartics2Module.forRoot([Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics])
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics } from 'angulartics2/ga';
...
constructor(
    angulartics2GoogleAnalytics: Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics
) {
    angulartics2GoogleAnalytics.startTracking();
}
```

angulartics2GoogleAnalytics.startTracking() throws an error though: 
**Angulartics2: startTracking() does not exist on type 'Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics'**.

Can anyone tell me why? I'm using Angular 5.2.8.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out RXJS 6.0.0 is required: https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2/issues/266. I believe using RXJS 5 causes angulartics2/ga not to be found, hence the error mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue myself by looking in to some new docs but then I just figure out there is no `startTracking()` in the sources https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2/blob/master/src/lib/providers/ga/ga.ts

Also see this https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2/wiki/Google-Analytics

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(angulartics2GoogleAnalytics: Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics) {}
}
```

UPDATE: the `startTracking()` exists on the [next branch](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2/blob/next/src/lib/providers/ga/ga.ts#L36) through, added 6 days ago. The `next` branch does not released as a new version yet so the package version you are getting from `npm` does not contain any new code from the `next` branch.