# Property 'startTracking' does not exist on type 'Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics'

Tags: angular, typescript, angulartics2

I've followed the readme of https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2. but I get the error:

`ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(21,33): error TS2339: Property 'startTracking' does not exist on type 'Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics'.`

I'm assuminging I have some problems with the versions of my dependencies, a similiar thread ([Angulartics2: startTracking() does not exist on type 'Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51584799/angulartics2-starttracking-does-not-exist-on-type-angulartics2googleanalytic)) Suggests the dependecies should be "rxjs": "6.0.0" and typesript should be higher than 2.6. However I still get the problem.

Any ideas?

my package.json

`{
  "name": "flow-app",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build:preprod": "ng build --prod --source-map --configuration=preprod --base-href /dist/",
    "build:prod": "ng build --prod --build-optimizer --configuration=production --base-href /dist/"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
    "angulartics2": "^6.3.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-opd-popup": "^1.1.21",
    "rxjs": "6.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.0.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14",
    "ajv": "^6.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2"
  }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to update Angular to version 6.x.x when using rxjs 6.x.x. Meaning I also had to use the newest version of angulartics2.
This is my package.json now

```
{
  "name": "flow-app",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build:preprod": "ng build --prod --source-map --configuration=preprod --base-href /dist/",
    "build:prod": "ng build --prod --build-optimizer --configuration=production --base-href /dist/"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
    "ajv": "^6.10.0",
    "angulartics2": "^7.0.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-opd-popup": "^1.1.21",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"
  }
}
```